# sum of cases in grand-parent, parents, children,, and etc

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

What I need is to count the total number of cases on: `parent cities`, `districts`, and `regions`

**So let me please tell you what the situation is and what I have done so far**

---

I have two tables `[cities]` & `[covid19cities]`

---

***The [cities] table:*** 
*reference table*

**Structure is:**

```
------------------------------
| id | parent_id | city_name |
------------------------------
```

**Cities levels is:**

```
 - Region          //[its parent_id = 0]
 -- District       //[its parent_id = the region id]
 ---- Parent-city  //[its parent_id = the district id]
 ------ Child-city //[its parent_id = the parent-city id]
```

---

***The [covid19cities] table:***

**Structure is:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| id | city_id | date | n_cases | r_cases | d_cases |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

So each day we fill `[covid19cities]` with the different cases in different cities:

`n_cases` = new covid-19 cases; `r_cases` = recovered cases; `d_cases` = deceased cases

---

**Up to this point:**

1. I am able to get the sum of cases (e.g. new cases) in each city using query like this:

   ```
   SELECT  sum(`n_cases`) AS city_n_cases, cities.name AS city_name,
           cities.id AS city_id,
       FROM  covid19cities
       INNER JOIN  cities  ON cities.id = covid19cities.city_id
       WHERE  covid19cities.city_id = '#'
   ```

   2. I am able to get sum of all cases (e.g. new cases) in all cities:

```
SELECT 
sum(`n_cases`) AS total_n_cases, 
FROM 
covid19cities
```

---

**Now,** what I need is to count the total number of cases on:

- parent cities
- districts
- regions

So, how can I accomplish that? What I thought about is

1. to find all regions
2. within the fetch assoc while-loop I search for the districts of the this region
3. within the fetch assoc while-loop of the districts I search for the parent-cities
4. within the fetch assoc while-loop of parent cities I search for the children cities
5. count the sum and then added back-wards to the parent cities and from there to districts and then to regions!

**BUT** I believe this is not how it should be done.  However, I do not know how to keep tracking parent-children cities in such case.

I appreciate your advice and help.

Thanks

```
p.s. sorry for my English :/
```

Comment: If the levels are fixed, then 3 self joins will give you the hierarchy and you can use the rollup group by modifier to get the sums by parent.

Comment: what is the model you have prepared for cities level in your tables, it seems that it is not mentioned which column you have assigned this relationship with your model.
Or you want to consider them in a separate table and then making the related queries!?

Comment: @Shadow can you please explain how?

Comment: @Ebrahim.  Sorry but I couldn't understand what you mean?! covid19cities.city_id = cities.id

Comment: You have not mentioned how you maintain the hierarchy/relationships of cities, regions and ... in your table! I think

Comment: You should distinguish between the ids of them I think!

Comment: @Ebrahim I think you missed it!   check the cities table structure you will find the parent_id column

Comment: @sultan, I know, but its logic is not clear for the reader, I would say! maybe you should explain the relationship in more details

Comment: @SULTAN: it would really help if you could provide 5 to 10 rows of sample data for the 2 tables, along with the results that you exepct. That way, one would probably be able to provide relevant query(ies) for you use case.

Comment: @GMB, Thank you, I've seen your answer and I will try to apply it to my system.  If it didn't work I will provide you with sample data from my db.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following base query, that gives you the sum of each category of cases per `city_id`. We can get that information by looking at `covid19cities` only:

```
select 
    cvc.city_id,
    sum(cvc.n_cases) sum_n_cases,
    sum(cvc.r_cases) sum_r_cases,
    sum(cvc.d_cases) sum_d_cases
from covid19cities cvc
group by cvc.city_id
```

Now let's bring the `cities` table. This gives the same results, and you can display the city name too:

```
select 
    c.id   city_id,
    c.name city_name, 
    sum(cvc.n_cases) sum_n_cases,
    sum(cvc.r_cases) sum_r_cases,
    sum(cvc.d_cases) sum_d_cases
from covid19cities cvc
inner join cities c on c.id = cvc.city_id
group by c.id, c.name
```

Starting from there, we can follow the hierarchy upwards, level by level, by adding more joins on the `cities` table and changing the columns in the `select` and `group by` clauses.

Let's get the number of cases per *parent city*: we join the `cities` table a second time, with alias `pc` (for parent city):

```
select 
    pc.id   parent_city_id,
    pc.name parent_city_name, 
    sum(cvc.n_cases) sum_n_cases,
    sum(cvc.r_cases) sum_r_cases,
    sum(cvc.d_cases) sum_d_cases
from covid19cities cvc
inner join cities c  on c.id  = cvc.city_id
inner join cities pc on pc.id = c.parent_id
group by pc.id, pc.name
```

The next level is the *district*:

```
select 
    d.id   distict_id,
    d.name district_name, 
    sum(cvc.n_cases) sum_n_cases,
    sum(cvc.r_cases) sum_r_cases,
    sum(cvc.d_cases) sum_d_cases
from covid19cities cvc
inner join cities c  on c.id  = cvc.city_id
inner join cities pc on pc.id =  c.parent_id
inner join cities d  on d.id  = pc.parent_id
group by d.id, d.name
```

Finally, here is the query that gives the information at the upper level, that is the region:

```
select 
    r.id   region_id,
    r.name region_name, 
    sum(cvc.n_cases) sum_n_cases,
    sum(cvc.r_cases) sum_r_cases,
    sum(cvc.d_cases) sum_d_cases
from covid19cities cvc
inner join cities c  on c.id  = cvc.city_id
inner join cities pc on pc.id =  c.parent_id
inner join cities d  on d.id  = pc.parent_id
inner join cities r  on r.id  =  d.parent_id
group by r.id, r.name
```

---

As a more general thought: note that the complexity here comes from the fact that you are storing hierachical structure in the `cities` table. It would be much simpler to have separated tables to store each entity, with foreign keys to represent the relationships, like:

```
regions:        region_id, region_name
districts:      district_id, district_name, region_id
parent_cities:  parent_city_id, parent_city_name, district_id
cities:         city_id, city_name, parent_city_id
```

With this design, your last query would look like:

```
select 
    r.region_id,
    r.region_name, 
    sum(cvc.n_cases) sum_n_cases,
    sum(cvc.r_cases) sum_r_cases,
    sum(cvc.d_cases) sum_d_cases
from covid19cities cvc
inner join cities c         on c.id              = cvc.city_id
inner join parent_cities pc on pc.parent_city_id =  c.parent_city_id
inner join districts     d  on d.district_id     = pc.district_id
inner join regions       r  on r.region_id       =  d.region_id
group by r.region_id, r.region_name
```

That's the same number of joins, but things are stored in different tables so the query is much easier to write and read.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only 3 levels, not an arbitrary number of levels, I suggest that you are working too hard.  Have a single table with 3 columns for the region, district, and city spelled out in the table.  That's only a few thousand rows per day, so the lack of normalization will not lead to a huge disk expense.

If, on the other hand, this is a learning exercise, then get MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.2 and learn about "Recursive CTEs".